# Did Swami Prabhupada reject Advaita?

Tags: advaita, prabhupada

Did Swami Prabhupada reject Advaita with a direct statement anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He did reject Advaita as "actually not correct":

> Māyāvādī philosophers think that since the Supreme Personality of Godhead, the Absolute Truth, has become everything, He has no separate existence. Their philosophy is called advaita-vāda.
>
> Sri Kṛṣṇa is the origin of everything. Kṛṣṇa is everything. Everything rests in the body of the Lord, yet the Lord is not everywhere. Māyāvādī philosophers think that since the Supreme Personality of Godhead, the Absolute Truth, has become everything, He has no separate existence. **Their philosophy is called advaita-vāda.** **Actually, however**, **their** **philosophy** **is not correct**... There are always two entities—the seer and the seen. The seer is a part of the whole, but he is not equal to the whole. The part of the whole, the seer, is also one with the whole, but since he is but a part, he cannot be the complete whole at any time. This acintya-bhedābheda—simultaneous oneness and difference—is the perfect philosophy propounded by Lord Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu.

Hope your question refers to Advaita-vada and not Advaita Acharya.Advaita Acharya was a devotee of Mahaprabhu and one of the five Tattvas preached by the Gaudiya Vaishnavas.

Reference : https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Advaita_vada_philosophy

Comment: Why did it get divided into small parts St the beginning?